# The diff between conf management and rendzvous example of ZooKeeper primitives

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is rendezvous a generalization of conf management? Because I think in the former scenario, the ZooKeeper node notifies the others about the update of configuration, and in the latter, ZooKeeper notifies everything that needs to be synchronized
Here's the link of the paper:https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/papers/zookeeper.pdf

The original text is located at **3.4 Examples of Primitives** of the **Zookeeper service** section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I intended this as a comment, as it is a bit longish, I am putting it in the answer section*

The concept is simple enough. In ZK you can set watches, once a watch is set by a client (with e.g. read data) an event (exactly one) is sent to the client by ZK, if the data in the ZNode changes (now persistent watches are also supported).

This is useful in cases where either a configuration (data) is not yet available during startup (example given in the paper; the ZNode must exist) or the configuration can change at runtime.

One example is change of database password, for example, if there is a DB connection pool and org policy requires all passwords to be reset in 30 days, the app server can create a watch on ZNode and re-int the DB pool when the password changes.

Refer: [ZK-Docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches) for details. The paper you mention, essentially explains the concept of watches through it's 'rendezvous' example.